# Aggregate reference member and temporary lifetime

Tags: c++, reference, initialization, aggregate, temporary

Given this code sample, what are the rules regarding the lifetime of the temporary string being passed to `S`.

```
struct S
{
    // [1] S(const std::string& str) : str_{str} {}
    // [2] S(S&& other) : str_{std::move(other).str} {}

    const std::string& str_;
};

S a{"foo"}; // direct-initialization

auto b = S{"bar"}; // copy-initialization with rvalue

std::string foobar{"foobar"};
auto c = S{foobar}; // copy-initialization with lvalue

const std::string& baz = "baz";
auto d = S{baz}; // copy-initialization with lvalue-ref to temporary
```

According to the standard:

N4140 12.2 p5.1 (removed in N4296)

> A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the
>   constructor exits.

N4296 12.6.2 p8

> A temporary expression bound to a reference member in a mem-initializer is ill-formed.

So having a user defined constructor like `[1]` is definitively not what we want. It's even supposed to be ill-formed in the latest C++14 (or is it?) neither gcc nor clang warned about it.
Does it change with direct aggregate initialization? I looks like in that case, the temporary lifetime is extended.

Now regarding copy-initialization, [Default move constructor and reference members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33379327/default-move-constructor-and-reference-members) states that `[2]` is implicitly generated. Given the fact that the move might be elided, does the same rule apply to the implicitly generated move constructor?

Which of `a, b, c, d` has a valid reference?

Comment: There is no exception from the lifetime extensions of temporaries for aggregate initialization, hence the lifetime of the temporary will get extended. This guarantees a proper lifetime for the temporary created in the case "direct-initialization".

Comment: what do you mean "the move might be elided" ? Reference binding can't be elided, `str_` binds directly to `other.str`.  (the `std::move` has no effect)

Comment: @M.M I mean most compilers will perform a direct initialization rather than using the move constructor. Yes `std::move(other).str` is the same as `other.str` for references and has no effect here

Comment: The change that made binding temporaries to reference members in mem-initializers ill-formed was done because of [CWG 1696](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1696), which is post-C++14 (status: DRWP). Its implementation status in [clang is "unknown"](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html). Not sure if such a list exists for gcc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The lifetime of temporary objects bound to references is extended, unless there's a specific exception. That is, if there is no such exception, then the lifetime will be extended.

From a fairly recent draft, N4567:

> The second context [where the lifetime is extended] is when a
> reference is bound to a temporary. The temporary to which the
> reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a
> subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of
> the reference except:
>
> - (5.1) A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) persists until the completion of the
>   full-expression containing the call.
> - (5.2) The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not extended; the temporary is
>   destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
> - (5.3) A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer (5.3.4) persists until the completion of the full-expression
>   containing the new-initializer.

The only significant change to C++11 is, as the OP mentioned, that in C++11 there was an additional exception for data members of reference types (from N3337):

> - A temporary bound to a reference member in a constructor’s ctor-initializer (12.6.2) persists until the constructor exits.

This was removed in [CWG 1696](http://wg21.cmeerw.net/cwg/issue1696) (post-C++14), and binding temporary objects to reference data members via the mem-initializer is now ill-formed.

---

Regarding the examples in the OP:

> ```
> struct S
> {
>     const std::string& str_;
> };
>
> S a{"foo"}; // direct-initialization
> ```

This creates a temporary `std::string` and initializes the `str_` data member with it. The `S a{"foo"}` uses aggregate-initialization, so no mem-initializer is involved. None of the exceptions for lifetime extensions apply, therefore the lifetime of that temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference data member `str_`.

---

> ```
> auto b = S{"bar"}; // copy-initialization with rvalue
> ```

**Prior to mandatory copy elision with C++17:**
Formally, we create a temporary `std::string`, initialize a temporary `S` by binding the temporary `std::string` to the `str_` reference member. Then, we move that temporary `S` into `b`. This will "copy" the reference, which will not extend the lifetime of the `std::string` temporary.
However, implementations will elide the move from the temporary `S` to `b`. This must not affect the lifetime of the temporary `std::string` though. You can observe this in the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

#define PRINT_FUNC() { std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n"; }

struct loud
{
    loud() PRINT_FUNC()
    loud(loud const&) PRINT_FUNC()
    loud(loud&&) PRINT_FUNC()
    ~loud() PRINT_FUNC()
};

struct aggr
{
    loud const& l;
    ~aggr() PRINT_FUNC()
};

int main() {
    auto x = aggr{loud{}};
    std::cout << "end of main\n";
    (void)x;
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/EhmY7FTEYCTNamcz)

Note that the destructor of `loud` is called before the "end of main", whereas `x` lives until after that trace. Formally, the temporary `loud` is destroyed at the end of the full-expression which created it.

The behaviour does not change if the move constructor of `aggr` is user-defined.

**With mandatory copy-elision in C++17:** We identify the object on the rhs `S{"bar"}` with the object on the lhs `b`. This causes the lifetime of the temporary to be extended to the lifetime of `b`. See [CWG 1697](https://wg21.link/cwg1697).

---

For the remaining two examples, the move constructor - if called - simply copies the reference. The move constructor (of `S`) can be elided, of course, but this is not observable since it only copies the reference.

Comment: Perhaps `auto b = S{"bar"};` will change for C++17?  The intent of the changes to prvalues is that `S s{x};` should be exactly identical to `auto s = S{x};`, although I haven't checked the exact wording that would cover this case.

Comment: @M.M It's not very easy for me to understand the new wording (*"the initializer expression is used to initialize the destination object"*, 17.6.1) but https://wg21.link/cwg1697 suggests that `b` and `S{"bar"}` refer to the same object, therefore the lifetime of the temporary should be extended to the lifetime of `b`. I don't think the compilers currently implement this, though (see Live demo of answer).