# move constructor and assignment operator for class with a reference member

Tags: c++, constructor, move, move-semantics, move-constructor

I'm new to move semantics, and I've been reading several resources that explain the correct way of defining a move constructor and assignment operator. All introductory material seems to use a class with a pointer member variable as examples. However I don't understand what to do with reference data members and class data members. For example:

```
Class A
{
(...)
private:
   ClassB& reference_member;
   ClassC object_member;
}
```

What should a move constructor and move assignment operator do, supposing that ClassB and ClassC are non-trivial classes (with several member variables that are too expensive to copy). I want to be able to move instances of A around effectively.

Comment: For `ClassC` you just move it, and rely on the fact that tha class itself has proper move-constructor and/or move-assignement. As for the reference, it's not data that your class owns, so how to deal with that depends on your use-case.

Comment: That's strange you didn't find anything about this, I think this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34486446/7143595) and [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) contain the tips you need